# Why are some of my USB 3.0 connectors green and not the usual blue color?

Tags: usb, motherboard, usb-3

I just got a new computer from a local shop in town. On the back it has two black USB 2.0 connectors. Two blue USB 3.0 connectors, and two green USB 3.0 connectors?

Does anyone know why two of them are green? What does that mean?

Comment: You should provide the make/model of your motherboard so we can investigate more specifically. Also, perhaps look as its user's guide an see if you can identify why they are a different colour...

Comment: Maybe they're environmentally friendly ports?  :-)

Comment: My new PC with ASUS motherboard defines the 'green' ones as USB 3.1 Gen 2

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Colors):

- Black or White = USB 1.x or USB 2.0.
- Blue = USB 3.0
- Teal blue = USB 3.1.
- Yellow, Orange or Red = high current/sleep-n-charge ports.

Teal:

[image: Teal Swatch]

Teal looks pretty green to me ;)  And since there's no official color spec for USB, yours could be a different (greener) shade even.

I'm going to say your new computer has USB 3.1 on it, and those are the "green" ports you are seeing.

You can probably confirm that by looking at your system/motherboard user's guide.